Facebook debugger broken?
I noticed yesterday when I posted a link to my website on facebook that the tags and everything were wrong, and completely outdated, when i say outdated I mean over 4 years outdated.
I've used the debugger to scrape and scrape and scrape and every bit of information it shows is STILL that 4 year outdated information that is not contained in any webpage.
I have even used a dummy index html with all the proper information and nothing. it is like Facebook isn't even connecting to my URL as I don't even see any access request in any log file.
I have scoured through a ton of posts here, attempted to use the answers here and nothing.
I don't understand how it can scrape something that hasn't been anywhere on the server in over FOUR years
WHAT HAVE I DONT TO TRY TO FIX IT.

Dummy html file as i use php, as I found in several posts here(that code is at the bottom)

Scoured my server for any remnant of this data(including the sitepad system I use to use(its not there)

In June I actually reformatted the entire server to fix my DNS issues(bad upgrade for ubuntu 16 to 22)

appended the URL inside the debugger with the refresh wording i found here(did not work)

Checked Logs, there is no reference in the logs that the scraper is actually connecting to any portion of the website.


Bing, Google, Yahoo all reference it fine(They haven't scrapped the new revamp yet as I just took it live, but the previous revamp information is there)
It is just facebook
LINK & CODE
What it shows currently...
Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties

og:url  https://evcomp.org/

og:title    Evlite Computers – Built With Love

og:description  Evlite Computers Services you can trust, Quality you can afford Solutions for a small planet Laptop Maintenance & Repair Is it just dirty? or is that hard drive bad? Power supply faulty? We can list a whole bunch of issues, but we can't. Just bring it to use for repair! Cheapest Diagnoses Our diagno...

og:image    https://evcomp.org/sitepad-data/uploads//2021/06/197175306_220693006405591_2067482021254840918_n.jpg

og:image:alt    197175306_220693006405591_2067482021254840918_n

Debugger URL
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fevcomp.org
meta data it should have
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="Quality, Professional, Affordable Repairs" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="Evlite Comp LLC" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Quality, Professional, Affordable Repairs" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />       
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://evcomp.org/FB_IMG_1689112529430.jpg" />      
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://evcomp.org" />


I get a nice big "SSL Error Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid." error on that debugger. I'd start there.

This question is similar to: Facebook not recognizing my SSL certificate. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Per https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=evcomp.org&s=74.208.12.147&hideResults=on&latest you have the same issue as ^; an intermediate chain cert is missing.
